# Grails spring security 3 field authentication

Tags: grails, authentication, spring-security

I need to authenticate the users of my application using spring security but I need to have a 3 field authentication which will have a `username`, `password` and `companycode`. Since the app is handling too many companies so it needs to have the company code.

I have been trying to address this issue and have came across this link which is written by @BurtBeckwith -
http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1090

Now questions and doubts arises because this blog was written in 2011 and was used at the time of Grails 1.4. So have anyone came across any such issue in the recent past? Still we need to change this much to implement the 3 field login?

Are there any shortcuts to implement this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though much has changed in the world of Grails since Burt wrote that blog entry, Spring security itself has not changed fundamentally.

The approach he outlines is **still arguably the best approach** to adding additional authentication credentials (e.g. organization) without limiting your ability to further enhance security to leverage this additional paradigm.

So in short, *no* there are no shortcuts to implement this. As Burt has said many times, doing security **right** is hard. However, if you do it right, you don't have to worry about it after it is done.

Comment: Thank you Joshua for your reply. I will start implementing that. But I am keeping the question open so may be someone has something more to say.

Comment: You're welcome, and I'd be curious to see what other options are available. Perhaps even Burt may stop by and offer his expert opinion (or confirm the above).

Comment: Yep, there has been a lot of internal refactoring and package restructuring in Spring Security since then, but the fundamental approaches are pretty much the same. I need to update that blog post a bit, mostly with changes from the 1.x plugin style to the 2.0 style (e.g. 'plugins' -> 'plugin'), but also to update the Spring Security classes that are in different packages now. I'll be doing a new version of that talk at Greach in April (and probably both GR8Confs) so feel free to contact me directly before then if something doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you Burt for your reply. I'll be implementing it and will let you know if something doesn't work.